# What's new in LaBSE v2?

Tags: tensorflow, bert

I can't find what's new in LaBSE v2 (https://tfhub.dev/google/LaBSE/2). What are the main highlights of v2 versus v1? And how did you find out?

Comment: I did tests comparing LaBSE v2 versus v1. v2 is about twice as slow and returns almost identical results than v1... :(